# java check condition after clicking on save button before commit

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

i want to put if else or switch statement which is more suitable for checking employee count before commit.where i put my if else or switch code . i want restriction on employee if count is 5 then its show message "reached maximum employee limites" otherwise allow commit.
i am new in java plz someone help me to solve this

```
    public String cmdSave_action()

{
    // my code before 

    {
    DeptSet result;
       try {
           dbo.connect();

           result = 
                   dbo.execSQL("select count(*) from empmasterinfo where mainid='ORGElement' and designationid='?') "
                               (inputText_ORGElement.getValue() != null ? 
             ""));

        result = dbo.execSQL(sSQL);

      catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       finally 
       {
       dbo.close();                         
       }
       return null;
    }}}

    // my code above

  {  
    Global.PerformIteratorAction(this.bindings, "Commit");
    AdfFacesContext afContext = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    afContext.getProcessScope().put("EmployeeID", 
                                    Global.getCurrRowFieldValue("EmpmasterinfoViewIterator", 
                                                                "Employeeid"));
    if (afContext.getProcessScope().get("AddEdit").toString().equals("0"))

    {
        Global.PerformIteratorAction(this.bindings, 
                                     "EPR_TRANSFER_APPLICANT_INFO");
        Global.PerformIteratorAction(this.bindings, "eprGenerateApPlan");
    }
    return null;
}}
```

My Error Log

```
Error(149,12): 'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'
Error(154,36): , expected
Error(157,34): field SQL not found in class hcm.view.backing.empprofile.EmployeeMasterInfo_Add
Error(159,11): illegal start of expression
Error(159,11): ; expected

E:\HCM\ViewController\src\hcm\view\backing\empprofile\dbo.java
Error(13,16): method does not return a value
```

Comment: -1 For bad code formatting.

Comment: It would be more to the point to disable the button unless the prerequisites are already true.

Answer (score 0):

Please close Your `try catch` block properly

```
try{

}catch(Exception e){

}finally{

}
```

And Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Answer (score 0):

`catch` and `finally`  are within try `block`

```
try {
//code
}
catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
finally {
dbo.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you vinayat  for help can you plz help me which condition is more suitable for multiple condition if else or switch

Comment: @user3024346 the switch statement is faster to execute than the if-else-if ladder. This is due to the compiler's ability to optimise the switch statement. In the case of the if-else-if ladder, the code must process each if statement in the order determined by the programmer. However, because each case within a switch statement does not rely on earlier cases, the compiler is able to use branch tables in such a way as to provide the fastest execution

Answer (score 0):

Using an IDE will help you with indentation and proper formatting while writing code. e.g [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

For the first error close the try-catch blocks properly
And for the second error: Since your method is declared as `public String cmdSave_action()`, you should return a `String` value at the end of the method. The `return` statement is missing in your code.